# What is the significance of 'ordinals' in an ORDER BY clause with CASE conditions

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, case

I have a 'names' tables with two columns: last_name, first_name

```
last_name  first_name
---------  ----------
Basu       Rohini
Khan       Amartya
Nandy      Upanita
Ghosh      Shankha
NULL       Claire
NULL       Amelie
```

When I am doing (1st SQL):

```
    SELECT last_name, first_name FROM names
    ORDER BY
        CASE 
            WHEN last_name IS NOT NULL THEN 3
            ELSE 100
        END,
        last_name DESC
```

I'm getting an output:

```
last_name  first_name
---------  ----------
Nandy      Upanita
Khan       Amartya
Ghosh      Shankha
Basu       Rohini
NULL       Amelie
NULL       Claire
```

But when I'm doing this (2nd SQL):

```
    SELECT last_name, first_name from names
    ORDER BY
        CASE 
            WHEN last_name IS NOT NULL THEN 3
        END,
        last_name DESC
```

Or this (3rd SQL):

```
    SELECT last_name, first_name from names
    ORDER BY
        CASE 
            WHEN last_name IS NOT NULL THEN 100
            ELSE 3
        END,
        last_name DESC
```

I'm getting an output starting with last_name as NULL and first_name in ascending order, followed by the non-null last_names in descending order:

```
last_name  first_name
---------  ----------
NULL       Amelie
NULL       Claire
Nandy      Upanita
Khan       Amartya
Ghosh      Shankha
Basu       Rohini
```

My questions:

- Why is the 1st SQL giving an output with last_name sorted in a descending manner, for non-null last names?
- Why I'm not getting an error in 1st SQL for 'CASE WHEN last_name IS NOT NULL THEN 3' saying 'Expressions 3 and last_name in ORDER BY clause are same'?
- Why I was able to give any random numbers like 3 and 100, under the CASE statement? As per the SQL standard, this number can only be any non-negative integer value upto the degree of the number of columns. How is the integer within CASE statement working?

Comment: No, those 3 and 100 are simply integer values as used here - not ordinal position! 3 goes before 100, i.e. non-null names before null names.

Comment: Your case expression returns 3 for non-null names, and 100 for null names. Order by that value!!!

Comment: Yeah, I've got it now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't ordinals - they're just numbers. Each of your `CASE` expressions essentially boils down to "assign all of the rows with a `NULL` last name `<some fixed value>` and all of the non-`NULL` last name rows `<some other fixed value>`" and then perform a sort on those fixed values.

So all that these `CASE` expressions do is ensure that all of the `NULL` rows will appear before/after the non-NULL rows. The specifics of which way around that is depends on the specific fixed values you're employing in each query.

> Why is the 1st SQL giving an output with last_name sorted in a descending manner, for non-null last names?

Because that's what the second expression in your `ORDER BY` clause asks for?

> Why I'm not getting an error in 1st SQL for 'CASE WHEN last_name IS NOT NULL THEN 3' saying 'Expressions 3 and last_name in ORDER BY clause are same'?

Because the expressions aren't the same, and even if they were, SQL doesn't prevent you from asking for redundant/pointless orderings (i.e. you can specify more expressions in an `ORDER BY` clause than are required to uniquely determine each rows final output position and no error is produced)

---

> Why I was able to give any random numbers like 3 and 100, under the CASE statement? As per the SQL standard, this number can only be any non-negative integer value upto the degree of the number of columns. How is the integer within CASE statement working?

Because, again, these aren't ordinals. In order to be considered an ordinal, you have to supply a *constant* literal integer as the entire `order by expression` - not a larger expression, such as these `CASE` expressions.

Comment: Thanks Damien. I'm not understanding how are these non-NULL names being mapped to 3 and NULL names being mapped to 100?

Comment: @riyaB - I'm not sure I understand your question. If you don't understand what a `CASE` expression does at all, why are you randomly adding them to your queries? If you do understand what a `CASE` expression does, I'm not sure how you can be unclear on how `3` and/or `100` are being assigned.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I got it now. :)
I was still thinking that the output from CASE statements will act as column ordinals for the ORDER BY clause. 
It is actually sorting on the two categories of row values i.e null and not null, assigning them to the numbers and then ordering on the numbers.